# Bash multiarray and IFS

Tags: arrays, bash, ifs

I have a problem in my bash script.

I would split a string into an (indexed named) array:

The string can have this values: `status=online clients=5 name=Server`
the string can also have several commands have like these (that's the problematic):
`status=online clients=5 name=Server|status=offline clients=0 name=Server_2`

**First Question: How can i split, or should i check, if this "|" exists?**

**Second Question: I must split now this values into an named array like from string: `status=online clients=5 name=Server` and the array looks like:**

```
[status] = [online]
[clients] = [5]
[name] = [Server]
```

And if the separator "|" exists, i must get the results in 2 (or more) arrays:

```
$mainarray [0]
[status] = [online]
[clients] = [5]
[name] = [Server]

$mainarray [1]
[status] = [offline]
[clients] = [0]
[name] = [Server2]
```

And for example, with `echo $mainarray[0][status]` i would get "online".

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: `bash` doesn't handle nested arrays well at all. (It's not impossible, but it's a very strong indication that you should be using a different language.)

Comment: What do you need to do with these split records once you have them?

Comment: @EtanReisner evaluate and/or compare the results, i think that arrays for this are the best solution...

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you have external tools that need to get involved here? Is the comparison against external data or just internal? An `awk` script might be a solution here if the analysis is internal only. Arrays are the right idea but `bash` might not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo-multidimensional associative arrays.

```
str='status=online clients=5 name=Server|status=offline clients=0 name=Server_2'
n=0
declare -A ary

# split the string on "|"
IFS='|' read -ra sets <<< "$str"

# interate over the sets of variables to populate the array
for set in "${sets[@]}"; do
    IFS=' ' read -ra pairs <<< "$set"
    for pair in "${pairs[@]}"; do
        IFS='=' read var value <<< "$pair"
        ary["$n,$var"]=$value
    done
    ((n++))
done

# now, what do we have?
for key in "${!ary[@]}"; do 
    printf "%s => %s\n" "$key" "${ary["$key"]}"
done
```

The order of the output is undetermined

```
0,clients => 5
1,status => offline
1,name => Server_2
0,status => online
1,clients => 0
0,name => Server
```